# Why in JavaScript, MySql timestamp are not converted the same on mobile then on desktop?

Tags: javascript, mysql, django

I have a Ajax request to fetch Django data in Json. I receive the response and everything is ok, I keep dateTime in my Django app as naive date since I don't have to manage timezone. I want `date/time` to be showed like they are saved.

Ok in my javascript, when I do a:

```
console.log(item.fields.timeStamp);
```

I receive:

```
2020-03-29T21:00:00.143
```

On both desktop and my iPhone, and that is wath I expect, but when I do that:

```
alert(new Date(item.fields.timeStamp));
```

I receive:

```
Sun Mar 29 2020 20:05:21 GMT-0400 (heure d’été de l’Est)
```

On my desktop and:

```
Sun Mar 29 2020 16:05:21 GMS-0400 (EDT)
```

And that is totally wrong!!

So all `timeStamp` in my app are totally off on mobile devices.

What can be my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with timeZone manage. Its ideal that you save all dates in UTC format on database and converts it in each client according to timezone the you want.

You could do it using native javascript

```
console.log(new Date('2020-03-29T21:00:00.143').toLocaleString('es-ES', {timeZone: 'America/Bogota'}));
console.log(new Date('2020-03-29T21:00:00.143').toLocaleString('es-ES', {timeZone: 'Asia/Shanghai'}));
```

or with moment and moment-timezone libraries

```
const format = 'YYYY/MM/DDTHH:mm:ss.ZZZ';
const formatOut = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss';
console.log(moment('2020-03-29T21:00:00.143', format).tz('America/Bogota').format(formatOut));
console.log(moment('2020-03-29T21:00:00.143', format).tz('Asia/Shanghai').format(formatOut));
```

Comment: I know i have a problem with timezone, but i don't want to manage timezone. Our timezone are changing from summer time to normal time and i don't really want to play with that. My question is about the difference in javascript interpretation of the data time data between normal desktop/laptop computer and mobile device. Why are they managing time differently?